# manually trigger on screen keyboard for touch devices on contenteditable field

Tags: javascript, focus, windows-10, keyboard-events, soft-keyboard

I have a web app with some contenteditable fields. When they receive focus I would like to trigger the on screen keyboard but it is not appearing.

I've even tried to overlay some invisible input fields and passing the focus on to the contenteditable fields, to no avail (I think it doesn't fire because it's invisible).

I need it to work in the latest chrome on a microsoft surface pro 3 with windows 10.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same issue.